# Calculating the days difference between previous visit time to current visit time for same customer (same group) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to calculate the time difference(in days) between the customer's previous visit out time and the customer's latest visit in time.

`time difference = latest in time - previous out time`

Here is a sample of input data

[image]

sample output table

[image]

The approach I have tried so far groupby based on customer ID and rank

```
temp['RANK'] = temp.groupby('customer ID')['in time'].rank(ascending=True)
```

but I am unsure that how to calculate the difference.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). How is count `21 days` from sample  data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) to get the previous `out time` within the group. Substracted by current `in time`. Then, use [`dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) to get the number of days of the timedelta between `in time` and `out time` within the group, as follows:

```
# convert date strings to datetime format
df['out time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['out time'], dayfirst=True)
df['in time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['in time'], dayfirst=True)

df['Visit diff (in days)'] = (df['in time'] - df['out time'].groupby(df['customer ID']).shift()).dt.days
```

**Data Input:**

```
print(df)

   customer ID             out time              in time
0            1  05-12-1999 15:20:07  05-12-1999 14:23:31
1            1  21-12-1999 09:59:34  21-12-1999 09:41:09
2            2  05-12-1999 11:53:34  05-12-1999 11:05:37
3            2  08-12-1999 19:55:00  08-12-1999 19:40:10
4            3  01-12-1999 15:15:26  01-12-1999 13:08:11
5            3  16-12-1999 17:10:09  16-12-1999 16:34:10
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   customer ID            out time             in time  Visit diff (in days)
0            1 1999-12-05 15:20:07 1999-12-05 14:23:31                   NaN
1            1 1999-12-21 09:59:34 1999-12-21 09:41:09                  15.0
2            2 1999-12-05 11:53:34 1999-12-05 11:05:37                   NaN
3            2 1999-12-08 19:55:00 1999-12-08 19:40:10                   3.0
4            3 1999-12-01 15:15:26 1999-12-01 13:08:11                   NaN
5            3 1999-12-16 17:10:09 1999-12-16 16:34:10                  15.0
```

Comment: Thanks  @jezrael  I'm so happy my solution liked by a top master :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
temp.groupby('customer ID').apply(lambda x: (x['in time'].max() - x['out time'].min()).days )
```